# How to create a slideshow player with Raphael.js to load slides into separate html divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, raphael, slideshow

I'm looking to make a slideshow player with Raphael.js.  I would like it to be a plugin so it can be used again in the future.

Here is an example straight from the creator of Raphael, but it doesn't meet my needs:

[image: Raphaeljs+iPad splitview demo]

http://raphaeljs.com/jsconfeu/ In this example, Dimitry stores slides in an array and fire them sequentially. Seems to work well.

However I am looking for a way to load slides into separate divs (on different paper elements) to go with my jquery splitview model.

The main idea: 
1. Users can select a slide from the left navbar panel on the iPad.
2. Each slide can be loaded separately into the right slideviewer panel.

Here's my HTML code so far:

```
<!-- Demo slide 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="demo1_page1">

  <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false">
    <h1>Mobility Bootcamp</h1>
  </div><!-- /header -->

  <div data-role="content"> 
    <div class="container"></div> //<----Here is the container div
    <a href="#demo1_page2">Next slide</a>
  </div><!-- /content -->

  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="ew-footer" 
      class="ui-splitview-hidden">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#main" class="ui-btn-active" data-transition="slideup">Main</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#demo" data-transition="slideup">Demos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
  </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- Demo slide 2 -->
<div data-role="page" id="demo1_page2">
  <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false">
    <h1>Classroom</h1>
  </div><!-- /header -->

  <div data-role="content">  
    <div class="container"></div>//<--------Here is the container div
    <a href="#demo1_page1">Previous slide</a>
    <a href="#demo1_page3">Next slide</a>
  </div><!-- /content -->
```

And the Javascript:

```
// Here is the function that contains everything needed to 
//create a new slide and fill it with Raphael info.
var createContainer = function(selectedSlide) {
//Clear existing slide
$('#[id*="slide"]').remove();

// Create a new div with parameters.
$('<div/>', {
    id: 'slide' + selectedSlide,
    class: 'slide',
    text: 'container'+selectedSlide,
}).appendTo('.container'); // append it to container div

var container = "slide"+selectedSlide;

alert('just created container: '+ container);
// load the slide
    slides[selectedSlide](container);
};

var slides = [
0, //offset array for simplicity

// slide 1
function(container){
    console.log('slide 1 created!');
    var paper = new Raphael(container, 730, 600);
     var background = paper.rect(0, 0, 730, 600).attr({opacity: 1});
    background.attr({'gradient':'90-#444-#fff'});
}];
// is fired whenever a page is loaded.
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

// set the hashString to the current hash in the browser bar.
var hashString = window.location.hash;
hashString = hashString.split("demo1_page");

// set the selected slide to the hashString
var selectedSlide = hashString[1];

//  alert("currentSlide = "+container);

//Create the container for Raphael
    createContainer(selectedSlide);
});
```

Are there any existing slideshow player examples with Raphael.js that will load slides into separate divs?

Comment: Stack overflow is a single question/answer site, not a forum to discuss all the awesome new features and ideas for programs we are going to do.  You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.  Try to align your questions with the will of the creators of this site, Jeff and Joel who specify which kinds of questions to not ask: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Good advice, that was asked in ignorance back when I first began entering the programming world. I have sense grown in understanding and appreciation for stackoverflow and hope to contribute back as much as possible in the future with more focused questions.

Comment: Excellent, we need more soldiers to fend off the rivers of nonsense entering this site (how is babby formed need ansers URGENT!!!) style questions.  If you want the inside scoop on getting from 1 reputation to 5k rep, then from 5k to 20k, burn these to a CD and listen to them all in the car.  https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/?W4  The creators of this site are truly legendary programmers.